# Proving Inequalities With Mathematical Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

I'm currently working on this problem:

$$ 1 + 2^n + ≤ 3^n \text{ for all }  ≥ 1 $$

So far, I have:

Basis Step:
$ 1 + 2^1 ≤3^1 $
$ P(1) \text{ is true} $

Inductive Step: Assume P(k) holds, prove P(k+1)

$P(k) = 1 + 2^k ≤ 3k$

$ P(k+1) = 1 + 2^{k+1} ≤ 3^{k+1} \text{ (I.H.)}$

$ 1 + 2^{k+1} = 1 + 2 * 2^k$

$ \quad \quad \, \, \quad  = 2 * 2^k + 1 ≤ 2 * 3^k$

But now, I'm unsure what to do next. Any help would be aprreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: The next step is $2 \cdot 3^k < 3 \cdot 3^k$

Comment: $2 \cdot 2^k+1 < 2(2^k+1) \leq 2 \cdot 3^k < 3 \cdot 3^k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done. $$\quad \quad \, \, \quad   2 * 2^k + 1 ≤ 2 * 3^k<3*3^k=3^{k+1}$$

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain how you got to 3 * 3^k?

Comment: we know $2<3$. you can multiply both sides by $3^k$ and get $2*3^k< 3*3^k = 3^{k+1}$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
1+2^{k+1}&=1+2\cdot 2^{k}\\
&\leq 1+2\cdot(3^{k}-1)\\
&=2\cdot 3^{k}-1\\
&\leq 2\cdot 3^{k}\\
&\leq 3\cdot 3^{k}\\
&=3^{k+1}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The inductive step:
$$1+2^{n+1}=1+2\cdot 2^n=1+2^n+2^n\le 3^n+2^n\le 3^n+3^n+3^n=3\cdot 3^n=3^{n+1}.$$

Without induction:
$$1+2^n\le 3^n=(1+2)^n=1+A+2^n, \ \ A\ge 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$3^{k+1}\ge 3\cdot 2^k +3 > 2^{k+1}+1$$

Answer (score 0):

First use induction to prove $2^{n} < 3^n$.
Then $1 + 2^n \leq 3^n$ immediately follows.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to factor the difference of powers:

$$3^n-2^n = \underbrace{(3-2)}_{=1} \underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i 3^{n-1-i}}_{\ge 1} \ge 1$$

Rearranging gives $1+2^n \le 3^n$.